# Поиск совпадений в строке php

Tags: php

Допустим, есть строка:

> привет меня зовут Крокодил Гена, я потерял чебурашку

Есть массив: `$arr = array('Гена', 'потерял');`

Как можно с помощью функции `in_array()` или же регулярных выражений (я не знаю как правильнее в данной ситуации) найти совпадение в данной выше строке, хотя бы с одним словом в массиве `$arr`?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример Вашего кода

Comment: Вы пробовали сами хоть как-то решить задачу и как (пусть даже не получилось) ?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию **[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)**:

```
<?php

$string = 'привет меня зовут Крокодил Гена, я потерял чебурашку';
$arr = array('Гена', 'потерял');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (strpos($string, $arr[$i])) 
        echo 'Слово ' . $arr[$i] . ' найдено в строке';
}
```

Либо можно реализовать это через регулярные выражения, функцией **[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
if (preg_match("/$arr[$i]/", $string)) {
    echo 'Слово ' . $arr[$i] . ' найдено в строке';
}
```

---

В вопросе указано про функцию **[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)**. В таком случае, нужно разделить строку на массив, потому что данная функция работает лишь с массивами. Сделаем это через функцию **[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)**, так как в строке могут присутствовать и запятые, а в таком случае проще сделать через regex.

```
<?php

$string = 'привет меня зовут Крокодил Гена, я потерял чебурашку';
$string = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);

$arr = array('Гена', 'потерял');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (in_array($arr[$i], $string)) 
        echo 'Слово ' . $arr[$i] . ' найдено в строке';
}
```

Я бы использовал первый пример, потому что он проще для понимания и реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Самый изящный и, скорее всего, самый быстрый вариант провернуть такое - это сделать простенькую проверку шаблона (регулярного выражения):

```
<?php

$subject = 'привет меня зовут Крокодил Гена, я потерял чебурашку';
$pattern = '/'.implode('|', array('Гена', 'потерял')).'/';
$matches = array();

print_r($pattern);

echo 'Result: '.preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches)."\n";
print_r($matches);
```